# How can I off-screen render?

Tags: windows, opengl, off-screen

I have a problem with off-screen rendering with OpenGL.
I searched for a lot about FBO and PBO but nothing was helpful for me.
I guess the matter was from memDC which was made by CreateCompatibleDC.

Here is a part of my code

```
void COpenGLWnd::ShowinWnd(int ID)
{
    m_hDC = ::GetDC(m_hWnd);
    memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(m_hDC);
    SetDCPixelFormat(memDC);

    m_hRC = wglCreateContext(memDC);
    VERIFY(wglMakeCurrent(memDC, m_hRC));
    m_isitStart = 0;

    GLuint pbo;
    glGenBuffersARB(1,&pbo);
    glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, pbo);
    glBufferDataARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, (m_WndWidth * 3 + 3) / 4 * 4 * m_WndHeight, NULL, GL_STREAM_READ);

    glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, pbo);

    switch(ID)
    {
    case T_FADEIN:
         GLFadeinRender();
        break;
    case T_PARANORAMAL:
         GLParanormalRender();
        break;
    case T_3DCUBE:
         GL3DcubeRender();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, pbo);
    glReadBuffer(GL_BACK);
    glReadPixels(0,0,m_WndWidth,m_WndHeight,GL_BGR_EXT,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    BYTE* data = (BYTE*) glMapBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, GL_READ_ONLY_ARB);
    if(data)
    {
        SaveBitmapToDirectFile(data);    //this makes bitmap file with pixel BYTE array, "data".
        glUnmapBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB);
    }

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB,0);

    SwapBuffers(memDC);

    glDeleteBuffers(1,&pbo);

    wglMakeCurrent(memDC, NULL);
    wglDeleteContext(m_hRC);
    DeleteDC(memDC);
    ::ReleaseDC(m_hWnd, m_hDC);
}
```

If I run this programm without memDC and CreateContext on m_hDC, nothing was matter. Well rendered on window, well written bitmap file. But I want to render in off-screen and only saving bitmap files. How can I handle this?

Comment: thanks for you answer!, but how can I use SelectObject then? Could you recommend it me again please?

Comment: I inserted new code on initializing step like __m_hMemBmp = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(m_hDC, m_WndWidth, m_WndHeight); ::SelectObject(memDC, m_hMemBmp);__
but still nothing changed

Comment: I use Borland and under it I never get bitmap rendering running. So if your problems persist you can draw to Texture without any additional DC/RC needed (only the target window is needed)... but the size of texture is limited on some cards/drivers a lot more than the screen resolution so may be you have to use more textures for coverage.

Answer (score 1):

MemDCs will automatically drop you back to the old, OpenGL-1.1 software rasterizer. This rasterizer is very limited, does not support any kind of modern features, like FBOs, PBuffers and so on.

If you want a GPU accelerated OpenGL context you need to create this on a regular window (or a PBuffer DC, but to get a PBuffer DC you need a window first). You need the window just for getting the context, you don't have to render there and the window can stay hidden all the time (omit the `ShowWindow` call of the creation process). With a valid pixelformat set for the window create the OpenGL context on its HDC.

Since you already have a window, just go with that then.

With the OpenGL context from a regular window you can then use FBOs for off-screen rendering.